# raspicam slow for real-time usage

Tags: python, raspicam, opencv

I am currently using a raspberry 3 model B and a raspicam version 1.2. I want to use it to detect colour using opencv. I'm taking input using imshow and then using image procesing to obtained the desired result.

I am able to do this on my setup but it is very slow and im unable to understand how and where to use threading.

Could someone help with how can threading be incorporated or any other method to increase the frames rate per second?

python code used:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
   pass

# Tracker bar Definition
cv2.namedWindow("Tracking")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.createTrackbar("LS", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("LV", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("UH", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("US", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("UV", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)

# Loop of the video

while True:
   _, frame = cap.read()
   cv2.circle(frame, (320, 240), 1, (255, 0, 0), 3)

 hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 l_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LH", "Tracking")
 l_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LS", "Tracking")
 l_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("LV", "Tracking")
 u_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("UH", "Tracking")
 u_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("US", "Tracking")
 u_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("UV", "Tracking")
 l_b = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
 u_b = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])
 blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(hsv, (15, 15), 5)
 mask = cv2.inRange(blur1, l_b, u_b)
 eroded = cv2.erode(mask, (3, 3), iterations=2)
 dilated = cv2.dilate(eroded, (3, 3), iterations=2)
 res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=dilated)  # used to set the region we need

 contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
 cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
 x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)

 cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), ((x + w), (y + h)), (255, 255, 255), 2)

# centroid
 cx = int((w / 2) + x)
 cy = int((h / 2) + y)
 cv2.circle(frame, (cx, cy), 1, (255, 255, 255), 3)

 if cx == 320 and cy == 240:
     print("Throw")
 elif cx > 320 and cy > 240:
     print("Move up and left")
 elif cx < 320 and cy < 238:
     print("Move down and right")
 elif cx > 320 and cy < 240:
     print("Move down and left")
 elif cx < 320 and cy > 240:
     print("Move up and right")
 elif cx == 320 and cy < 240:
     print("Move down")
 elif cx == 320 and cy > 240:
     print("Move up ")
 elif cx > 320 and cy == 240:
     print("Move Left")
 elif cx < 320 and cy == 240:
     print("Move right")

cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
cv2.imshow("result", res)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# release
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Without any code, it is complicated to find an answer. What programming language do you use ? Try stackoverflow for question related to openCV.

Comment: I'm currrently using python.

Comment: @apurva_b, when you run your script, what is your CPU usage in percentage ?